# How to inline three text elements that are overlapping?

Tags: html, css

This is what's happening [Overlapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWdq1.png).
I need the elements to be in line with each other like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6kRm.png). I used the `position: absolute` method. I want the space between the text to be variable (I want to be able to edit it).

```css
.navbar {
  background: var(--button);
  height: 121px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar .container .center-nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="#">
        <img id="Logo" src = "images/Logo Official.svg" alt="Logo" width="80" height="80"/> 
    </a>
    <div class="container">
            <nav class="space">
                        <a class="center-nav" href="#">About</a>
                        <a class="center-nav" href="#">Updates</a>
                        <a class="center-nav" href="#">Who am I?</a>
            </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't see a similar result when I run the code you provided. How do you expect us to help?

Comment: It shows up like that on my side in vs code.

Comment: you have to add the displey for the nav tag and make it flex and justify content should be space around

Comment: You are basically setting all anchor tags at same place.  If you what all three of them in center than center their parent element.

Comment: That's not valid CSS. If  you're actually using SASS or LESS or some other preprocessor, please [edit] your question with the CSS output.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.